# differentiability of a distance function

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty set, and define the function:
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\quad,\quad f(x):=\inf_{a\in A}|x-a|$$

My question is -  Is there an explicit characterization of all points $x\in\overline{A}$ at which $f$ is differentiable?

##### My attempt

**Claim:** Let $x\in\overline{A}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff for every sequence of points ${\{y_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $y_n\to x$ and $y_n\neq x$ for every $n$, there exists a sequence ${\{a_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty\subset A$ s.t. $\left|\frac{y_n-a_n}{y_n-x}\right|\to0$.

- $\Rightarrow$ : $f$ is differentiable at $x\in\overline{A}$, thus there is a sequence of points ${\{c_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty\subset A$ s.t. $c_n\to x$, and so: $$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(c_n)-f(x)}{c_n-x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{0-0}{c_n-x}=0$$ Let ${\{y_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence s.t. $y_n\to x$ and $y_n\neq x$ for every $n$. By properties of $f$, for every $n$ there exists a point $a_n\in A$ s.t. $|y_n-a_n|<f(y_n)+\left|\frac{y_n-x}{n}\right|$, and so: $$\left|\frac{y_n-a_n}{y_n-x}\right|\leq\frac{f(y_n)+\left|\frac{y_n-x}{n}\right|}{|y_n-x|}=\left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(x)}{y_n-x}\right|+\frac{1}{n}\to f'(x)=0$$
- $\Leftarrow$ - Let ${\{y_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence s.t. $y_n\to x$ and $y_n\neq x$ for every $n$. We assume there exists a sequence ${\{a_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty\subset A$ s.t. $\left|\frac{y_n-a_n}{y_n-x}\right|\to0$. Then we conclude: $$\left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(x)}{y_n-x}\right|=\frac{f(y_n)}{|y_n-x|}\leq\left|\frac{y_n-a_n}{y_n-x}\right|\to0$$ Thus $f$ is differentiable at $x$ (and $f'(x)=0$).

In my opinion, this is quite a nice property, because in some sense it means that not only that $x$ is a limit point of $A$, but also that we can "approximate" every sequence that converges to $x$ with a sequence of elements of $A$. On the other hand, It doesn't give us a clear idea of how $A$ really behaves around $x$.

Is there any characterization of the points $x\in\overline{A}$ at which $f$ is differentiable which is more straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain of your functions was $\mathbb R^2$, then this would be a standard result: $f$ is differentiable except possibly at points that lie on the [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) or the skeleton of the set $A$.

I’ve never seen a definition of skeleton for subsets of $\mathbb R$, but I suppose we can borrow the definition from $\mathbb R^2$: a point belongs to the medial axis of $A$ if it is equidistant from two or more points of the boundary of $A$.

For more details, see

Michel Delfour and Jean-Paul Zolésio,  Shapes and Geometries, second edition, SIAM, 2011.

Honglin Luo, Xianfu Wang, and Brett Lukens, "Variational Analysis on the Signed Distance Functions," JOTA, vol. 180(3), March 2019, pages 751-774.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check out those references. Actually what I am looking for is to know when exactly points on the skeleton are points of differentiability.

Comment: I think the answer is “almost never” (at least for the kind of shapes that I deal with).